# Laravel Filament: sum and count repeater

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-livewire

I'm making a form using [filament](https://filamentadmin.com/). I want to count the number of `repeater` I make, and the sum of the value I input.

[image: What I expected]

I want to make the default value of `Total area` is the sum of `Field area`, and the default value of `Number of fields` is to count the `Field` I generate. After reading the [documentation](https://filamentadmin.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields), I don't think there are such features. But, I just want to make sure if there is a trick to make this happen.

I tried to `count($get('fields')`, but it thrown an error:

```
count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given
```

Here's my code:

```php
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Card::make([
                    Grid::make(2)
                        ->schema([
                            TextInput::make("total_area")
                                ->label("Total area")
                                ->postfix('m²')
                                ->disabled()
                                ->default(fn (Closure $get) => $get('field')),
                            TextInput::make("number_of_field")
                                ->label("Number of fields")
                                ->disabled()
                                ->default(fn (Closure $get) => count($get('fields'))),
                        ]),

                ])->columnSpan(1),

                Card::make([
                    Select::make("measurement_type")
                        ->label("Measurement type")
                        ->required(),

                    Repeater::make('fields')
                        ->label('Field')
                        ->schema([
                            TextInput::make("field")
                                ->label("Field area")
                                ->postfix('m²')
                                ->required(),
                        ])
                ])->columnSpan(1)
            ])->columns(2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Dan's [answer](https://github.com/laravel-filament/filament/discussions/) with some modification of my own, I should have used `placeholder` instead of `default`.

My working code:

```php
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                   Card::make([
                      Grid::make(2)
                        ->schema([
                            TextInput::make("total_area")
                                ->label("Total Area")
                                ->postfix('m²')
                                ->disabled()
                                ->placeholder(function (Closure $get) { 
                                    $fields = $get('fields');
                                    $sum = 0;
                                    foreach($fields as $field){
                                        foreach ($field as $value){
                                            if ($value == ""){
                                                $value = 0;
                                            }
                                            $sum += $value;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return $sum;
                                }),
                            TextInput::make("number_of_fields")
                                ->label("Number of Fields")
                                ->disabled()
                                ->placeholder(fn (Closure $get) => count($get('fields'))),
                        ]),

                ])->columnSpan(1),

                Card::make([
                    Select::make("measurement_type")
                        ->label("Measurement Type")
                        ->options(MeasurementType::all()->pluck('name'))
                        ->required(),

                    Repeater::make('fields')
                        ->schema([
                            TextInput::make("field")
                                ->label("Field Area")
                                ->postfix('m²')
                                ->numeric()
                                ->reactive()
                                ->required()
                        ])
                        ->reactive()
                ])->columnSpan(1)
            ])->columns(2);
    }
```

Result as expected:

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$get` variable and get the repeator Property. And you can use the Placeholder props and Set the `content` to it.
Here is the result

[image]

```
public static  function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Card::make([
                    Grid::make(2)
                        ->schema([
                            Placeholder::make("total_area")
                                ->label("Total area")
                                ->content(function ($get) {
                                    return collect($get('fields'))
                                        ->pluck('field')
                                        ->sum();
                                }),
                            Placeholder::make("number_of_field")
                                ->label("Number of fields")
                                ->content(function ($get) {
                                    return collect($get('fields'))
                                        ->pluck('field')
                                        ->count();
                                })
                        ]),

                ])->columnSpan(1),

                Card::make([
                    Select::make("measurement_type")
                        ->label("Measurement type")
                        ->required(),

                    Repeater::make('fields')
                        ->label('Field')
                        ->schema([
                            TextInput::make("field")
                                ->label("Field area")
                                ->postfix('m²')
                                ->required()
                                ->reactive(),
                        ])
                ])
                    ->reactive()
                    ->columnSpan(1)
            ])->columns(2);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is working, but unfortunately, I cannot accept this because several days ago I already have got the answer from the maintainer of filament. So, I will post my own answer on his behalf. I'm still gonna upvote yours.